# postgresql INSERTs NULL values from SELECT COS(another field) query

Tags: sql, math, trigonometry, postgresql-9.3

If I run

```
SELECT 
(cos(radians(spa.spa_zenithangle)))
FROM generic.spa;
```

I get a sensible range of results from -1 to 1. but if I run this insert statement all the resulting values in the `spa.spa_cos_zenith` field are `NULLs`

```
INSERT INTO generic.spa
(spa_cos_zenith)
SELECT 
(cos(radians(spa.spa_zenithangle)))
FROM generic.spa;
```

**The table definition is:**

```
CREATE TABLE generic.spa (
 spaid INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('generic.spa_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
 measurementdatetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
 spa_zenithangle NUMERIC(7,3),
 spa_cos_zenith DOUBLE PRECISION,
 CONSTRAINT spa_pk PRIMARY KEY(spaid)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

Anyone know why the COS functions returns results ok but they cant be inserted into another field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
UPDATE generic.spa
    SET spa_cos_zenith = cos(radians(spa.spa_zenithangle));
```

`INSERT` inserts new rows, so you are duplicating the rows.  The only column in the new rows is the `COS()` value.  Nothing changes in the old rows.